# How to check an IBAN number using the Apache IBANCheckDigit?

Tags: java, android, apache, validation, iban

In my Android app, I'm trying to check if an IBAN bank account number is valid. This supposedly can be done using the [Apache IBANCheckDigit](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.0/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/IBANCheckDigit.html). I now try do so as follows:

```
IBANCheckDigit a = new IBANCheckDigit();
try {
    String checkDigit = a.calculate("MY_IBAN_NUMBER_HERE");
    Boolean b = a.isValid(checkDigit);
    Log.e("isValid: ", b.toString());
} catch (CheckDigitException e) {
    Log.e(this, "THIS IS AN ERROR");
}
```

This however, always prints `false`. Even if I insert my own (correct) IBAN-number, it also gives a `false`.

Does anybody know how to use this Apache IBANCheckDigit? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if the IBAN check digits are valid you should use the `isValid` method only:

```
Boolean b = a.isValid("MY_IBAN_NUMBER_HERE");
Log.e("isValid: ", b.toString());
```

The `calculate` method would compute the check digits if you did not know them already.

Answer (score 2):

iban4j might be good choice for IBAN validation, which is validating not only check digit but also IBAN length, structure, character types, etc...

home page: https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/iban4j

Code Sample:

```
try {
    IbanUtil.validate("AT611904300234573201");
    // valid
} catch (IbanFormatException e) {
    // invalid
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```